# CDF of maximum of iid rvs

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having a small doubt regarding maximum of random variables. I have $$Z= \max\{ X_1, X_2,\dots X_p, \dots X_N\}$$ where all $X_i$ are independent, identically distributed. Now, If for sure, I know that $$X_p>X_{p+1}>\dots>X_N$$ the can i say that the CDF of $Z$,

$$\begin{align*}P(Z<z)&= P\left(\max\{ X_1, X_2,\dots X_p, \dots X_N\}<z\right)\\&=P\left(\max\{ X_1, X_2,\dots X_p\}<z\right)\\&=\left[P(X_1<z)\right]^{N-p-1}\end{align*}$$

How to find CDF of $Z$ in this case ? Is there any theorem that reduce the size of total variables for certain condition  ?

Comment: "Hey Doc, the machine works, we have gone back in time!!!" "No, Marty it is just a repost"  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035113/maximum-of-rvs-independent-and-identically-distributed...

Comment: The problem is similar, but there are differences,In this case, only one random variables are greater than others.

Comment: So, it is a simple special case of the other problem.

Comment: Some of us is not fortunate enough to understand probability theory as deeply as you do which is why the confusion. Let me rephrase my question in your terms, how to handle this special case ?

Comment: If you know that $X_p>X_{p+1}>\ldots>X_N$ then of course you know that $\{X_1,\ldots, X_p\}>X_{p+1},\ldots, X_N$ as in the other problem. So your result is again correct and the notion that you need to express it formally is that of conditional distribution (if necessary, otherwise what you have is correct). But ok, perhaps there is some better answer, that can help you more. Good luck with it and thanks for your kind words (despite me not being so kind :)!

Comment: $X_n$ are independent and you know *for sure* that $X_p > X_{p+1}>\dots > X_n$. Aren't they constant?